# Invisible reCAPTCHA - Missing required parameters: sitekey

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I am loading Invisible reCAPTCHA dynamically for every form with button that has class `g-recaptcha` .

Problem that I have is that captcha is not loading correctly and I am not sure why. I followed documentation on captcha website and I am not sure how and why I got this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Missing required parameters: sitekey
```

Does someone knows where is the problem?

Here is code I use:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&hl={{  app.request.locale|default(defaultLang) }}' async defer></script>
```

JS

```
var onloadCallback = function () {
    $("button.g-recaptcha").each(function () {
        var el = $(this);
        //SITE_KEY is actually hard coded string.
        //It is string that google provided. I just remove it for security reasons...
        grecaptcha.render($(el).attr("id"), {
            "sitekey": SITE_KEY,  
            "size": "invisible",
            "badge": "inline",
            "callback": function (token) {
                $(el).parent().find(".g-recaptcha-response").val(token);
                $(el).closest("form").submit();
            }
        }, true);
    });

    $("button.g-recaptcha").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        grecaptcha.execute();
    });
};
```

EXAMPLE OF HTML:

```
<button 
    type="submit" 
    id="submitReviewButton"
    class="btn btn-lg btn-submit btn--green g-recaptcha"
 >
    {{ "review.submit_your_review"|trans }}
</button>
```

Comment: So... do you have `var SITE_KEY = "......";` somewhere above that code?

Comment: @ChrisG I hard code it inside this function. I just remove it for "security" reasons. SITE_KEY is actually sitekey that google provides

Comment: Maybe mention that in your question then, given the error you're asking about :)

Comment: Oh sorry. I will update my question

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are missing an important part here. The api widget must rendered explicitly. Just add `render=explicit` to recaptcha api script.

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?
onload=onloadCallback
&render=explicit
&hl={{app.request.locale|default(defaultLang) }}' async defer>
</script>
```

Read the Google doc ([reCAPTCHA V2 | reCAPTCHA - Explicitly render the reCAPTCHA widget](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#explicit_render)).

Comment: Make also sure that if you pass in the `grecaptcha.render(container, params)` method a dom object as container, that it is actually a dom object and **not** a jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

If you are here only for working Recaptcha Invisible v2 code example:
1. Put id="recaptcha" on your form button
2. Add JavaScript

```
var recaptchaCallback = function() {
        $("button#recaptcha").each(function () {
            var el = $(this);
            grecaptcha.render($(el).attr("id"), {
                "sitekey": 'YOUR_GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_KEY',
                "size": "invisible",
                "badge": "bottomleft",
                "callback": function (token) {
                    $(el).closest("form").submit();
                }
            });
        });
    };
</script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=recaptchaCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting "Missing required parameters: sitekey" while using Wordpress with CForm Builder and Google Captcha RECaptcha, you have to put the Recaptcha Site Key under "Global Options" in the left-nav for the CForm Builder plugin.  You also need the same info in the Google Captcha plugin.  This may seem obvious, but I missed the CForm "Global Options" for a long time.